# Change the cursor to a crosshair when a button is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

Hello I need to turn the cursor into a crosshair while the user drags a button. The code below is not working:

```
$("button").draggable('cursor','crosshair');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `cursor` property of the draggable library, like this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    cursor: 'crosshair'
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to set a custom cursor through CSS you would need to use the `start` and `end` events of the jQuery draggable library to change the CSS `cursor` property of the `ui.helper`. Try this:

```js
$("#draggable").draggable({
  start: function(e, ui) {
    ui.helper.addClass('dragging');
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    ui.helper.removeClass('dragging');
  }
});
```

```css
.dragging { cursor: url('http://i.imgur.com/6r4pI7U.png'), crosshair; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable">
  <p>Drag me</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery UI docs https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/
`$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  cursor: "crosshair"
});`
Or if it is already initialized
`$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "cursor", "crosshair" );`

See here https://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/9844/